# PowerBI - Making a combo chart with data provided below

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I am trying to make a combo chart with the following data.
Table 1:

| Month | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 |

Table 2:

| Month | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Column A | 3.5 |
| 1 | Column B | 5.5 |

I would like to create a line chart of Column A & B for month 1 from table 1, and a bar chart for Column A & B for month 1 from table 2. Essentially to compare how they are stacking up against each other.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

I tried creating some DAX expressions, but none of them were really close to what I was looking for.

Edit: Expected Output:
a chart looking similar to this, where the o's are from column D
and the X's are from table 1 month 1.

| y-axis | body | body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 |  | o |
| 5 |  | X |
| 4 | o |  |
| 3 | X |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |
| x-axis | Column A | Column B |

Comment: Can you please provide your expected output ?

Comment: do you have a relationship between the tables?

Comment: no relationship between the tables